# Show ActivityIndicator 5 seconds in react native splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, settimeout, use-effect, activity-indicator

I wanted to show Activity indicator at least 5 seconds in this splash screen. I tried setTimeOut method but it doesn't worked. It disappeared quickly and show this warning also.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component.
> This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application.
> To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect
> cleanup function. at src/screens/SplashScreen.js:15:15 in
> setTimeout$argument_0

Here is my code and how can I fixed this?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { ActivityIndicator, View } from 'react-native';

const SplashScreen = () => {
  const [animate, setAnimate] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    closeActivityIndicator();
  }, []);

  const closeActivityIndicator = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      setAnimate(false);
    }, 5000);
  };

  return (
    <View
      style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', backgroundColor: '#06bcee' }}
    >
      <ActivityIndicator animating={animate} size="large" color="#ffffff" />
    </View>
  );
};

export default SplashScreen;
```

Comment: Do you use any library to control the splash screen? If not, please try this https://github.com/crazycodeboy/react-native-splash-screen to prevent the splash screen to hide automatically.

Comment: You can call `SplashScreen.hide();` after 5 sec.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot see where your navigation function call is. Anyways, what you can do is keep your *animate* state to true, it doesn't matter the activity indicator is animating. The other problem I see is that your component unmounts but your setTimout() doesn't get cleared so it keeps on updating your state. You can do something like this.

```html
const timerRef = React.useRef(null) // you can also import useRef() directly from 'react'

useEffect(() => {
  timerRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
    // code for navigation
  }, 5000);
  
  return () => clearTimeout(timerRef.current);
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That warning disappeared after clear the Timeout. useRef helps to do my job.

Comment: Glad that helped. 